# Docker's Centos 6.6 image not starting

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I have recently pulled a centos image from docker hub (v.6.6). I used

```
docker pull centos:6.6
```

Now when I list the images I have I can see

```
REPOSITORY      TAG                IMAGE ID            CREATED           SIZE
centos          6.6              d03626170061        10 months ago       203MB
```

However, when I try t start the container using the good old

```
docker run -ti d03626170061 bash
```

I don't get anything, the command just seems like it is executing something and no matter how long I wait nothing comes back.

I did my homework and checked if container was created (none created), if a process started (none started) and checked the images info (retrieved successfully).

**edit**

below are the host version info

```
C:\Users\Admin>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I can't find an error and the commands are running on my machine...

Comment: It seems like the issue solved it self when I changed the DNS used by docker to 8.8.8.8. not sure if that is the solution but oddly enough it worked.